# Update in mysql trigger not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm creating a trigger to execute after an insert is done into my checkin table but my update statement is not working

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS checkins_AINS$$

CREATE TRIGGER `checkins_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `checkins` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE client_id INT;
    DECLARE duplicate_record INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE bpoints INT;
    DECLARE business_id INT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062 SET duplicate_record = 1;

    SELECT checkinPoints, id INTO bpoints, business_id FROM businesses WHERE id = new.venue_id;

    INSERT INTO clients_checkins_summary(client_id, venue_id, first_checkin, last_checkin,visits)
    VALUES(new.client_id, new.venue_id, new.createAt, new.createAt,1);

    INSERT INTO clients_points_summary(client_id, business_id,current_points)
    VALUES(new.client_id, business_id,bpoints);

    IF duplicate_record = 1
    THEN
        UPDATE clients_checkins_summary
                SET last_checkin = new.createAt,
                    visits = visits + 1
        WHERE client_id = new.client_id and venue_id = new.venue_id;

        UPDATE clients_points_summary
                SET current_points = current_points + bpoints
        WHERE client_id = new.client_id and business_id = business_id;
    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Inserting:

```
insert into checkins(client_id,venue_id,points,createAt,updateAt)
values (52,19,1,now(),now());
```

for the first time works fine but when the case of update is trigger is entering into the if but is not update the value.

I trace the variables into a table and all the values are correct but update is not been updating anything.

I missing something?

Comment: Why not use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
....`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> am I missing something?

Possibly this

```
UPDATE clients_points_summary
            SET current_points = current_points + bpoints
    WHERE client_id = new.client_id and business_id = business_id;
```

The problem here is that your local variable `business_id` and the column name `clients_points_summary.business_id` are ambiguous. You could disambiguate as follows:

```
UPDATE clients_points_summary cps
    SET cps.current_points = cps.current_points + bpoints
    WHERE cps.client_id = new.client_id and cps.business_id = business_id;
```